# Synchronize Multiple Async Requests

Tags: java, concurrency, future

Given an async service which should be closed upon completion. I would like to execute multiple instances of a requests. When **all requests** are done I want to close the service. I'm wondering what's the best way to achieve that. So here is the code demonstrating the problem **but without actually closing the service**:

```
    class Service implements Closeable {
        public Service() {/*...*/}

        public ListenableFuture<Integer> processRequest(Integer param) {/*...*/}

        @Override
        public void close() {/*...*/}
    }

    public void proccessRequests(ArrayList<Integer> params) {
        Service svc = new Service();
        for (Integer param : params) {
            final ListenableFuture<Integer> res = svc.processRequest(param);
        }
    }
```

I'm considering different options to close the service:

- Use [CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) this way:

  ```
  public void processRequests(ArrayList<Integer> params) {
      Service svc = new Service();
      CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(params.size());
      for (Integer param : params) {
          final ListenableFuture<Integer> res = svc.processRequest(param);
          Futures.addCallback(res, new FutureCallback<Integer>() {
              @Override
              public void onSuccess(Integer integer) {
                  latch.countDown();
                  if (latch.getCount() == 0) {
                     svc.close();
                  }
              }

              @Override
              public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {
                  latch.countDown();
                  if (latch.getCount() == 0) {
                     svc.close();
                  }
              }
          });
      }
  }
  ```
- Use [CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) this way:

  ```
  public void processRequests(ArrayList<Integer> params) {
      Service svc = new Service();
      CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(params.size());
      for (Integer param : params) {
          final ListenableFuture<Integer> res = svc.processRequest(param);
          Futures.addCallback(res, new FutureCallback<Integer>() {
              @Override
              public void onSuccess(Integer integer) {
                  latch.countDown();
              }

              @Override
              public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {
                  latch.countDown();
              }
          });
      }
      latch.await();
      svc.close();
  }
  ```
- Similar to first option but using [AtomicInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html).

What's the best way to achieve that? first, second, third, none of these?

Comment: I would suggest using `ExecutorService`. http://www.baeldung.com/java-executor-service-tutorial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first solution with `CountDownLatch` looks fine, but there are some other methods.

Starting from version 20.0 `Futures` class has a `whenAllComplete` method designed exactly for that purpose. Using it you can write:

```
Service svc = new Service();
Futures.whenAllComplete(params.stream().map(svc::processRequest).collect(Collectors.toList())).call(() -> {
    svc.close();
    return null;
}, ForkJoinPool.commonPool());
```

You can also use Java 8 `CompletableFuture` class that has a similar method `allOf`:

```
CompletableFuture.allOf(params.stream().map(svc::processRequest).toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new))
    .thenAccept(v -> svc.close());
```

but in this case you have to make your `Service` return a `CompletableFuture`.

Comment: Thanks. In the second example, should I call `get` or any other instantiating function to actually make sure service is closed?

Comment: @HannaKhalil `thenAccept` will be called as soon as all futures complete, so you don't have to call `get`. But if you want some code to wait until they complete, you can add `.get()` of course. If you are worried that some of the futures may complete exceptionally, you should use `whenComplete` method instead of `thenAccept`: it will handle both normal and exceptional cases. Take a look at the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#whenComplete-java.util.function.BiConsumer-)

Comment: @HannaKhalil If that helped, please accept the answer