# How can I release the semaphore when two futures are completed?

Tags: java, spring, java-8, guava, future

I am having a Springboot java application that talks to cassandra database and also using google guava libaries.

currently i am facing a an issue. I have a semaphore object in the code.

in my my method i have to perform two write queries simulatenously using two objects( mapper and parameterisedListMsisdnMapper).

Firing each queries using the mappers returns ListenableFuture future  & ListenableFuture future1 objects .  How can I rewrited the below code, so that i will release the semaphore upon completion of both future and future1 object.

```
public class ParameterisedListItemRepository {
        
        public ParameterisedListItemRepository() {
         this.executor = MoreExecutors.directExecutor();
         this.semaphore = new Semaphore(getNumberOfRequests(session));
        }
       
       public void saveAsync(ParameterisedListItem parameterisedListItem) {
           try {
             semaphore.acquire();
             ListenableFuture<Void> future = mapper.saveAsync(parameterisedListItem);
             ListenableFuture<Void> future1 = parameterisedListMsisdnMapper.saveAsync( mapParameterisedList(parameterisedListItem));
             future.addListener(() -> semaphore.release(), executor);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException("Semaphore was interrupted.");
            }
       }
    
    }
```

appreciate any help

Comment: `Futures.whenAllComplete(future, future1).run(semaphore::release, executor)` should combine and release on either a success or failure.

Comment: yes that works thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Synchronize Multiple Async Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48351368/synchronize-multiple-async-requests)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used Futures.whenAllSucceed and it worked

```
  public void saveAsync(ParameterisedListItem parameterisedListItem) {
        if (parameterisedListItem.getId() == null) {
            parameterisedListItem.setId(UUID.randomUUID());
        }
        Set<ConstraintViolation<ParameterisedListItem>> violations = validator.validate(parameterisedListItem);
        if (violations != null && !violations.isEmpty()) {
            throw new ConstraintViolationException(violations);
        }

        Callable releasePermit = () -> { semaphore.release();
            return null;
        };
        
        try {
            semaphore.acquire();
            ListenableFuture<Void> future1 = mapper.saveAsync(parameterisedListItem);
            ListenableFuture<Void> future2 = parameterisedListMsisdnMapper.saveAsync( mapParameterisedList(parameterisedListItem));
            Futures.whenAllSucceed(future1, future2).call(releasePermit, executor);

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            //FIXME handle exception in better way
            throw new RuntimeException("Semaphore was interrupted.");
        }
    }
```